# How to Change my Visibility on ViewGroup if any value in my ViewGroup Kotlin Language?

Tags: kotlin, view, visibility

I want to change `Groupview.visibility = View.VISIBLE` to be `GroupView.visibility = View.GONE`. How should the code be?

this is my Activity.kt

```
if (viewModel.inputPosTableArea1.value !=  "") {
    btn_addtable1?.visibility = View.GONE
    table2?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    btn_addtable2?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

I hope when the add button is "clicked" it will change to something like this:

```
btn_addtable1.visibility = View.GONE
table2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
btn_addtable2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve? I wrote about `Groupview` but there is no such view in (this part of) code. Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is ViewGroup 2 (table2) does not appear even though inputPosTableArea has a value. This is my fragment.xml - https://pastebin.com/5D2v0791 - [link](https://pastebin.com/5D2v0791) . And this is my ViewModel https://pastebin.com/BUa5C3v7 - [link](https://pastebin.com/BUa5C3v7). @Boken